# Laravel Medialibrary site is crashing with "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: php, laravel, media-library, laravel-medialibrary

I am building a site where a user can upload pdf files, I use spatie/Medialibrary for this task and an hour ago everythngi was working great.
However, I needed to install imagick for thumbnail generation of pdf files. After successfully installing it, file upload stopped working now I get This site can't be reached whenever I try to upload a file.
Here's the line of code which my site breaks on (this is inside the FileController.uplaod function)

```
$filePdf->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $file))->toMediaCollection('pdfFiles', 'local');
```

[image: Website error]

Model is setup correctly, storage is linked, as I said, it was working splendid before installation of imagick so everything is configured correctly.
Here's the form setup from which uploaded file submit is called

```
<form id='SubmitForm' action='/uploadFile' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' autocomplete="off">
```

Here's the route setup

```
Route::post('/uploadFile', 'FileController@upload');
```

I need some help finding a solution for this because I have no idea where to even start. How can I even debug this sort of problem?
Php version 7.1.26
Laravel version 5.5
medialibrary version 6.0
I have tried googling out this issue but with no success.

Comment: You web server process will log this sort of error, you just need to find where the log file is stored.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have tried looking into xampp apache logs also php error log but found nothing there

Comment: What about Laravel's logs? Which is the thrown exception?

Comment: I have found that this is a problem with ghostscript...though it is installed on my machine.